# How to start MYSQL trigger after complete bulk insert?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have bulk insert job which insert more than 1000 records and based on inserted values, i would insert into another table using after insert trigger.

But triggering each row inserted in the table.So im getting duplicated values.  Please advise how to prevent the trigger on each row or any other alternative to handle the use case.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `cost_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `cost` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `finance`.`finance_master`
(`Source`,
`January`,
`February`,
`March`,
`April`,
`May`,
`June`,
`July`,
`August`,
`September`,
`October`,
`November`,
`December`) 
select ref.name,ref.owner,ref.department_id,c.source
c.Jan,
c.Feb,
c.Mar,
c.Apr,
c.May,
c.Jun,
c.Jul,
c.Aug,
c.Sep,
c.Oct,
c.Nov,
c.Dec 
from cost as c ,reference as ref where c.name = ref.name;

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting duplicates is that the trigger running the same exact statement after every insert without any reference to the record you just inserted. Based on your post it looks like you want to copy each new record to a different table. As such, you should use the keyword 'new' to reference the record that you are trying to insert. Something like :

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `cost_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `cost` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `finance`.`finance_master`
(`Source`,
`January`,
`February`,
`March`,
`April`,
`May`,
`June`,
`July`,
`August`,
`September`,
`October`,
`November`,
`December`) 
select new.source
new.Jan,
new.Feb,
new.Mar,
new.Apr,
new.May,
new.Jun,
new.Jul,
new.Aug,
new.Sep,
new.Oct,
new.Nov,
new.Dec 
from reference as ref where new.name = ref.name;

END
```

Also, I noticed that the table 'reference' is not part of the select clause of the trigger, so does it really need to be there? if your goal is to copy every record, you may miss some if they are not in the reference  table. In the end it just depends on what you are trying to do.

Having said all this, are you sure you want to use triggers for this in the first place? Since you are using bulk inserts, I assume performance is important and having triggers that run after each insert will not help your performance at all. Would it it be better to disable/remove the trigger and just have one copy statement once all the data has been inserted? It would definitely be better performance wise.

Comment: Just updated Question. I'm considering reference table column and just updated. My goal is just insert values to another table with matches with reference table.

Comment: Ok. In that case just use the 'new' keyword so that the trigger copies just the inserted row instead of all rows (as I showed above). Alternatively just have the insert statement as you have it run after all the inserts have run (not on the trigger)